# How to vectorize a data frame with several text columns in scikit learn without losing track of the origin columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have several pandas data series, and want to train this data to map to an output, df["output"].

So far I have merged the series into one, and separated each by commas.

```
df = pd.read_csv("sourcedata.csv")
sample = df["catA"] + "," + df["catB"] + "," + df["catC"]

def my_tokenizer(s):
    return s.split(",")

vect = CountVectorizer()
vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',tokenizer=my_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=1) 
train = vect.fit_transform(sample.values)

lf = LogisticRegression()
lfit = lf.fit(train, df["output"])
pred = lambda x: lfit.predict_proba(vect.transform([x]))
```

The problem is that this is a bag of words approach and doesn't consider
- the unique order in each category. ("orange banana" is different than "banana orange")
- text is one category has different significance than in another ("US" in one category could mean country of origin vs destination)

For example, the entire string could be:
`pred("US, Chiquita Banana, China")`
Category A: Country of origin
Category B: Company & Type of Fruit (order does matter)
Category C: Destination

The way I am doing it currently ignores any type of ordering, and also generates extra spaces in my feature names for some reason (which messes up things more):

```
In [1242]: vect.get_feature_names()[0:10]
Out[1242]:
[u'',
 u' ',
 u'  ',
 u'   ',
 u'    ',
 u'     ',
 u'   US',
 u'   CA',
 u'   UK']
```

Any suggestions are welcome!! Thanks a lot

Comment: what do you mean 'orange banana' ? is orange the company? or are these separate rows? ( in this case I don't know what it means to consider their unique order)

Comment: Well bag of words doesn't care about order, you are looking perhaps for N-Grams or perhaps a tf-idf approach so that context can be taken into consideration, you can also consider naive bayes or [tagging](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)

Comment: @maxymoo that is juts an example to demonstrate order, it bears no other significance. My example of "Chiquita Banana" would be more accurate for your understanding

Comment: @EdChum I have tried a mix of N-Grams, and all of the other variants you suggested. Unfortunately, what I want is to be able to specifically tell the "predictor" which feature its getting. So when I tell it pred("US, Chiquita Banana, China"), it knows that US=Source, Chiquita Banana = company/type, China = Destination. At the very least, it would be useful to know how to split features by comma instead of spaces. The custom tokenizer isn't working as intended at the moment. Would you know how to modify my token pattern to do this? (currently u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')

Comment: Sorry no, that's not my expertise, what you're asking about is not trivial it may be worth posting a question about the data science aspect on a different site such as http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ at the moment your question doesn't seem to be a programming issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, first let's prepare your data set, by selecting the relevant columns and removing leading and trailing spaces using `strip`:

```
sample = df[['catA','catB','catC']]
sample = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
```

From here you have a couple of options as how to vectorize this for a training set. If you have a smallish number of levels across all of your features (say less than 1000 in total), you can simply treat them as categorical variables and set `train = pd.get_dummies(sample)` to convert them to binary indicator variables. After this your data will look something like this:

```
catA_US   catA_CA ... cat_B_chiquita_banana   cat_B_morningstar_tomato ... catC_China ...
1         0           1                       0                            1   
...
```

Notice that that variable names start with their origin column, so this makes sure that the model will know where they come from. Also you're using exact strings so word order in the second column will be preserved.

If you have too many levels for this to work, or you want to consider the individual words in `catB` as well as the bigrams, you could apply your `CountVectorizer` separately to each column, and then use and use `hstack` to concatenate the resulting output matrices:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3))
train = sp.hstack(sample.apply(lambda col: vect.fit_transform(col)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping your dataframe to a list of dictionaries (where each entry represents a column) that represent your data and then write a custom tokenizer function that accepts a dictionary as input and outputs a list of features.

In the example below, I create a custom tokenizer that iterates through each of your columns so you can do whatever you want with them inside the function before appending them to your tokens list.  The data is then converted into a list of dictionaries using Pandas.

```
def my_tokenizer(d):
    # create empty list to store tokens
    tokens = []

    # do something with catA data
    tokens.append(d['catA'])

    # do something with catB data
    tokens.append(d['catB'].lower())

    return tokens

sample = df[['catA','catB','catC']]
vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=my_tokenizer)
train = vect.fit_transform(sample.to_dict(orient='records'))
```